# Kafka and zookeeper won't connect in a stable fashion on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to run kafka and zookeeper containers on AWS ECS but I'm stuggling to get them into a stable state.

Zookeeper - i'm using the official zookeeper:3.5 image and having ECS service discovery service give it an ip address at zk0.ecs.demo.com

Kafka - i'm using the latest wurstmeister/kafka image and having ECS service discovery service give it an ip address at kafka1.ecs.demo.com
configuring the KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT env var to look at zk0.ecs.demo.com and KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME is kafka1.ecs.demo.com:9092

Zookeeper starts up and seems to do so in a stable way, kafka then starts up and once it recognises zk0.ecs.demo.com as a host it will connect causing some errors in the zookeeper logs.

They seem to connect to each other until about a minute later when zookeeper dies and then kafka can't find it at the old IP address and dies and this all happens in a circular fashion.

The networking is wide open with all traffic allowed so i'm not sure that this is the problem.

I've tried running them on t2.large machines with 2048 memory so i'm not sure it's a resources problem.

I've tried 
- running ZK as a cluster of 3
- mapping the ports mapped to the hosts and unmapped
- using the ECS EC2 instance ip address instead of private dns

Can't seem to get it to work.

I've unfactored the terraform script i'm using to a single one if anyone wants to try to recreate it. (will need an ssh key at ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) https://gist.github.com/chestercodes/480dda384229adbd75fefea8fdf483d4

#### ZK logs

```
15:53:03 ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
15:53:04 Using config: /conf/zoo.cfg
53:04,044 [myid:] - INFO [main:QuorumPeerConfig@117] - Reading configuration from: /conf/zoo.cfg
53:04,051 [myid:] - INFO [main:QuorumPeerConfig@317] - clientPort is not set
53:04,051 [myid:] - INFO [main:QuorumPeerConfig@331] - secureClientPort is not set
53:04,058 [myid:] - WARN [main:QuorumPeerConfig@590] - No server failure will be tolerated. You need at least 3 servers.
53:04,072 INFO [main:DatadirCleanupManager@78] - autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3
53:04,072 INFO [main:DatadirCleanupManager@79] - autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0
53:04,072 INFO [main:DatadirCleanupManager@101] - Purge task is not scheduled.
53:04,073 INFO [main:ManagedUtil@46] - Log4j found with jmx enabled.
53:04,085 INFO [main:QuorumPeerMain@138] - Starting quorum peer
53:04,104 INFO [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@673] - Configuring NIO connection handler with 10s sessionless connection timeout, 1 selector thread(s), 4 worker threads, and 64 kB direct buffers.
53:04,112 INFO [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@686] - binding to port /0.0.0.0:2181
53:04,149 INFO [main:Log@186] - Logging initialized @753ms
53:04,204 WARN [main:ContextHandler@1339] - o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@8bd1b6a{/,null,null} contextPath ends with /*
53:04,204 WARN [main:ContextHandler@1350] - Empty contextPath
53:04,225 INFO [main:QuorumPeer@1349] - Local sessions disabled
53:04,225 INFO [main:QuorumPeer@1360] - Local session upgrading disabled
53:04,226 INFO [main:QuorumPeer@1327] - tickTime set to 2000
53:04,227 INFO [main:QuorumPeer@1371] - minSessionTimeout set to 4000
53:04,227 INFO [main:QuorumPeer@1382] - maxSessionTimeout set to 40000
53:04,227 INFO [main:QuorumPeer@1397] - initLimit set to 5
53:04,243 INFO [main:FileTxnSnapLog@320] - Snapshotting: 0x0 to /data/version-2/snapshot.0
53:04,246 INFO [main:QuorumPeer@798] - currentEpoch not found! Creating with a reasonable default of 0. This should only happen when you are upgrading your installation
53:04,249 INFO [main:QuorumPeer@813] - acceptedEpoch not found! Creating with a reasonable default of 0. This should only happen when you are upgrading your installation
53:04,256 INFO [main:Server@327] - jetty-9.2.18.v20160721
53:04,289 INFO [main:ContextHandler@744] - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@8bd1b6a{/,null,AVAILABLE}
53:04,311 INFO [main:AbstractConnector@266] - Started ServerConnector@14ab98c3{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
53:04,312 INFO [main:Server@379] - Started @921ms
53:04,312 INFO [main:JettyAdminServer@112] - Started AdminServer on address 0.0.0.0, port 8080 and command URL /commands
53:04,319 INFO [QuorumPeerListener:QuorumCnxManager$Listener@636] - My election bind port: localhost/127.0.0.1:3888
53:04,323 INFO [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):QuorumPeer@1055] - LOOKING
53:04,324 INFO [QuorumPeer[myid=1](plain=/0.0.0.0:2181)(secure=disabled):FastLeaderElection@894] - New election. My id = 1, proposed zxid=0x0
53:04,326 INFO [WorkerReceiver[myid=1]:FastLeaderElection@688] - Notification: 2 (message format version), 1 (n.leader), 0x0 (n.zxid), 0x1 (n.round), LOOKING (n.state), 1 (n.sid), 0x0 (n.peerEPoch), LOOKING (my state)0 (n.config version)
53:04,527 INFO [...)(secure=disabled):MBeanRegistry@128] - Unregister MBean [org.apache.ZooKeeperService:name0=ReplicatedServer_id1,name1=replica.1,name2=LeaderElection]
53:04,528 INFO [...)(secure=disabled):QuorumPeer@1143] - LEADING
53:04,531 INFO [...)(secure=disabled):Leader@63] - TCP NoDelay set to: true
53:04,531 INFO [...)(secure=disabled):Leader@83] - zookeeper.leader.maxConcurrentSnapshots = 10
53:04,532 INFO [...)(secure=disabled):Leader@85] - zookeeper.leader.maxConcurrentSnapshotTimeout = 5
53:04,538 INFO [...)(secure=disabled):Environment@109] - Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.5.3-beta-8ce24f9e675cbefffb8f21a47e06b42864475a60, built on 04/03/2017 16:19 GMT
53:04,539 INFO [...)(secure=disabled):Environment@109] - Server environment:host.name=ip-10-0-1-117.eu-west-1.compute.internal
53:04,539 INFO [...] - Server environment:java.version=1.8.0_151
53:04,539 INFO [...] - Server environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
53:04,539 INFO [...] - Server environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre
53:04,539 INFO [...] - Server environment:java.class.path=/zookeeper-3.5.3-beta/bin/../build/classes:/zookeeper-3.5.3-beta/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/zookeeper-3.5.3-beta/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/zookeeper-3.5.3-beta/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/zookeeper-3.5.3-beta/bin/../lib/netty-3.10.5.Fin
53:04,539 INFO [...] - Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
53:04,539 INFO [...] - Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
53:04,539 INFO [...] - Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
53:04,539 INFO [...] - Server environment:os.name=Linux
53:04,540 INFO [...] - Server environment:os.arch=amd64
53:04,540 INFO [...] - Server environment:os.version=4.9.85-38.58.amzn1.x86_64
53:04,540 INFO [...] - Server environment:user.name=zookeeper
53:04,540 INFO [...] - Server environment:user.home=/home/zookeeper
53:04,540 INFO [...] - Server environment:user.dir=/zookeeper-3.5.3-beta
53:04,540 INFO [...] - Server environment:os.memory.free=53MB
53:04,540 INFO [...] - Server environment:os.memory.max=889MB
53:04,540 INFO [...] - Server environment:os.memory.total=59MB
53:04,541 INFO [...:ZooKeeperServer@907] - minSessionTimeout set to 4000
53:04,541 INFO [...:ZooKeeperServer@916] - maxSessionTimeout set to 40000
53:04,542 INFO [...:ZooKeeperServer@159] - Created server with tickTime 2000 minSessionTimeout 4000 maxSessionTimeout 40000 datadir /datalog/version-2 snapdir /data/version-2
53:04,543 INFO [...:Leader@414] - LEADING - LEADER ELECTION TOOK - 15 MS
53:04,547 INFO [...:FileTxnSnapLog@320] - Snapshotting: 0x0 to /data/version-2/snapshot.0
53:04,564 INFO [...:Leader@1258] - Have quorum of supporters, sids: [ [1],[1] ]; starting up and setting last processed zxid: 0x100000000
53:04,578 INFO [...:CommitProcessor@255] - Configuring CommitProcessor with 2 worker threads.
53:04,587 INFO [...:ContainerManager@64] - Using checkIntervalMs=60000 maxPerMinute=10000
54:21,619 INFO [NIOServerCxnFactory.AcceptThread:/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory$AcceptThread@296] - Accepted socket connection from /10.0.1.91:44016
54:21,627 INFO [NIOWorkerThread-1:ZooKeeperServer@1013] - Client attempting to establish new session at /10.0.1.91:44016
54:21,630 INFO [SyncThread:1:FileTxnLog@204] - Creating new log file: log.100000001
54:21,638 INFO [CommitProcWorkThread-1:ZooKeeperServer@727] - Established session 0x1000001141b0000 with negotiated timeout 6000 for client /10.0.1.91:44016
54:21,708 INFO [ProcessThread(sid:1 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@880] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1000001141b0000 type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0x100000003 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers
54:21,725 INFO [ProcessThread(sid:1 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@880] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1000001141b0000 type:create cxid:0x6 zxid:0x100000007 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /config
54:21,733 INFO [ProcessThread(sid:1 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@880] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1000001141b0000 type:create cxid:0x9 zxid:0x10000000a txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/admin Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin
54:22,012 INFO [ProcessThread(sid:1 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@880] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1000001141b0000 type:create cxid:0x15 zxid:0x100000015 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/cluster Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /cluster
54:22,818 INFO [ProcessThread(sid:1 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@880] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1000001141b0000 type:setData cxid:0x22 zxid:0x10000001b txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/controller_epoch Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /controller_epoch
54:23,031 INFO [ProcessThread(sid:1 cport:-1)::PrepRequestProcessor@880] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1000001141b0000 type:delete cxid:0x32 zxid:0x10000001e txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/admin/preferred_replica_election Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election
```

#### Kafka logs

```
15:54:22 log.roll.hours = 168
15:54:22 log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
15:54:22 log.roll.jitter.ms = null
15:54:22 log.roll.ms = null
15:54:22 log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
15:54:22 log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
15:54:22 max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
15:54:22 max.connections.per.ip.overrides =
15:54:22 max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots = 1000
15:54:22 message.max.bytes = 1000012
15:54:22 metric.reporters = []
15:54:22 metrics.num.samples = 2
15:54:22 metrics.recording.level = INFO
15:54:22 metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
15:54:22 min.insync.replicas = 1
15:54:22 num.io.threads = 8
15:54:22 num.network.threads = 3
15:54:22 num.partitions = 1
15:54:22 num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
15:54:22 num.replica.alter.log.dirs.threads = null
15:54:22 num.replica.fetchers = 1
15:54:22 offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
15:54:22 offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
15:54:22 offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
15:54:22 offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
15:54:22 offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
15:54:22 offsets.retention.minutes = 1440
15:54:22 offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
15:54:22 offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
15:54:22 offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
15:54:22 offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
15:54:22 password.encoder.cipher.algorithm = AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
15:54:22 password.encoder.iterations = 4096
15:54:22 password.encoder.key.length = 128
15:54:22 password.encoder.keyfactory.algorithm = null
15:54:22 password.encoder.old.secret = null
15:54:22 password.encoder.secret = null
15:54:22 port = 9092
15:54:22 principal.builder.class = null
15:54:22 producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
15:54:22 queued.max.request.bytes = -1
15:54:22 queued.max.requests = 500
15:54:22 quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
15:54:22 quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
15:54:22 quota.window.num = 11
15:54:22 quota.window.size.seconds = 1
15:54:22 replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
15:54:22 replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
15:54:22 replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
15:54:22 replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
15:54:22 replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
15:54:22 replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
15:54:22 replica.lag.time.max.ms = 10000
15:54:22 replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
15:54:22 replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
15:54:22 replication.quota.window.num = 11
15:54:22 replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
15:54:22 request.timeout.ms = 30000
15:54:22 reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
15:54:22 sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
15:54:22 sasl.jaas.config = null
15:54:22 sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
15:54:22 sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
15:54:22 sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
15:54:22 sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
15:54:22 sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
15:54:22 sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
15:54:22 sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
15:54:22 security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
15:54:22 socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
15:54:22 socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
15:54:22 socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
15:54:22 ssl.cipher.suites = []
15:54:22 ssl.client.auth = none
15:54:22 ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
15:54:22 ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
15:54:22 ssl.key.password = null
15:54:22 ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
15:54:22 ssl.keystore.location = null
15:54:22 ssl.keystore.password = null
15:54:22 ssl.keystore.type = JKS
15:54:22 ssl.protocol = TLS
15:54:22 ssl.provider = null
15:54:22 ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
15:54:22 ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
15:54:22 ssl.truststore.location = null
15:54:22 ssl.truststore.password = null
15:54:22 ssl.truststore.type = JKS
15:54:22 transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 60000
15:54:22 transaction.max.timeout.ms = 900000
15:54:22 transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 3600000
15:54:22 transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
15:54:22 transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
15:54:22 transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
15:54:22 transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 1
15:54:22 transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
15:54:22 transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
15:54:22 unclean.leader.election.enable = false
15:54:22 zookeeper.connect = zk0.ecs.demo.com:2181
15:54:22 zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 6000
15:54:22 zookeeper.max.in.flight.requests = 10
15:54:22 zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 6000
15:54:22 zookeeper.set.acl = false
15:54:22 zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000
15:54:22 (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,162] INFO [ThrottledRequestReaper-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledRequestReaper)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,162] INFO [ThrottledRequestReaper-Request]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledRequestReaper)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,163] INFO [ThrottledRequestReaper-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledRequestReaper)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,198] INFO Log directory '/kafka/kafka-logs-ip-10-0-1-91.eu-west-1.compute.internal' not found, creating it. (kafka.log.LogManager)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,209] INFO Loading logs. (kafka.log.LogManager)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,221] INFO Logs loading complete in 12 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,234] INFO Starting log cleanup with a period of 300000 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,239] INFO Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,611] INFO Awaiting socket connections on 0.0.0.0:9092. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,642] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=1001] Started 1 acceptor threads (kafka.network.SocketServer)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,669] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1001-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,674] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1001-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,674] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1001-DeleteRecords]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,692] INFO [LogDirFailureHandler]: Starting (kafka.server.ReplicaManager$LogDirFailureHandler)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,713] INFO Creating /brokers/ids/1001 (is it secure? false) (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,717] INFO Result of znode creation at /brokers/ids/1001 is: OK (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,718] INFO Registered broker 1001 at path /brokers/ids/1001 with addresses: ArrayBuffer(EndPoint(kafka1.ecs.demo.com:9092,9092,ListenerName(PLAINTEXT),PLAINTEXT)) (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,720] WARN No meta.properties file under dir /kafka/kafka-logs-ip-10-0-1-91.eu-west-1.compute.internal/meta.properties (kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,789] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1001-topic]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,789] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1001-Heartbeat]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,801] INFO Creating /controller (is it secure? false) (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,801] INFO [ExpirationReaper-1001-Rebalance]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,813] INFO Result of znode creation at /controller is: OK (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,828] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,829] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,838] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=1001] Removed 0 expired offsets in 8 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,859] INFO [ProducerId Manager 1001]: Acquired new producerId block (brokerId:1001,blockStartProducerId:0,blockEndProducerId:999) by writing to Zk with path version 1 (kafka.coordinator.transaction.ProducerIdManager)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,929] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=1001] Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,936] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=1001] Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
15:54:22 [2018-05-04 15:54:22,937] INFO [Transaction Marker Channel Manager 1001]: Starting (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionMarkerChannelManager)
15:54:23 [2018-05-04 15:54:23,047] INFO [/config/changes-event-process-thread]: Starting (kafka.common.ZkNodeChangeNotificationListener$ChangeEventProcessThread)
15:54:23 [2018-05-04 15:54:23,070] INFO Kafka version : 1.1.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
15:54:23 [2018-05-04 15:54:23,070] INFO Kafka commitId : fdcf75ea326b8e07 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
15:54:23 [2018-05-04 15:54:23,071] INFO [KafkaServer id=1001] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
15:56:37 [2018-05-04 15:56:37,770] INFO Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x1000001141b0000, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:56:39 [2018-05-04 15:56:39,772] INFO Opening socket connection to server ip-10-0-1-117.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.0.1.117:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:56:40 [2018-05-04 15:56:40,798] WARN Session 0x1000001141b0000 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:56:40 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
15:56:40 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
15:56:40 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
15:56:40 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
15:56:40 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
15:56:42 [2018-05-04 15:56:42,475] INFO Opening socket connection to server ip-10-0-1-117.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.0.1.117:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:56:48 [2018-05-04 15:56:48,482] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 7583ms for sessionid 0x1000001141b0000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:56:48 [2018-05-04 15:56:48,482] INFO Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 7583ms for sessionid 0x1000001141b0000, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:56:50 [2018-05-04 15:56:50,254] INFO Opening socket connection to server ip-10-0-1-117.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.0.1.117:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:56:56 [2018-05-04 15:56:56,257] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 7674ms for sessionid 0x1000001141b0000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:56:56 [2018-05-04 15:56:56,258] INFO Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 7674ms for sessionid 0x1000001141b0000, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:56:57 [2018-05-04 15:56:57,591] INFO Opening socket connection to server ip-10-0-1-117.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.0.1.117:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:57:03 [2018-05-04 15:57:03,596] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 7238ms for sessionid 0x1000001141b0000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:57:03 [2018-05-04 15:57:03,596] INFO Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 7238ms for sessionid 0x1000001141b0000, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:57:04 [2018-05-04 15:57:04,890] INFO Opening socket connection to server ip-10-0-1-117.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.0.1.117:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:57:10 [2018-05-04 15:57:10,894] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 7198ms for sessionid 0x1000001141b0000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:57:10 [2018-05-04 15:57:10,894] INFO Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 7198ms for sessionid 0x1000001141b0000, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:57:12 [2018-05-04 15:57:12,388] INFO Opening socket connection to server ip-10-0-1-117.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.0.1.117:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:57:18 [2018-05-04 15:57:18,392] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 7398ms for sessionid 0x1000001141b0000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:57:18 [2018-05-04 15:57:18,392] INFO Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 7398ms for sessionid 0x1000001141b0000, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:57:20 [2018-05-04 15:57:20,162] INFO Opening socket connection to server ip-10-0-1-117.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.0.1.117:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:57:24 [2018-05-04 15:57:24,254] WARN Session 0x1000001141b0000 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:57:24 java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host is unreachable
15:57:24 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
15:57:24 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
15:57:24 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
15:57:24 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
15:57:25 [2018-05-04 15:57:25,482] INFO Opening socket connection to server ip-10-0-1-117.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.0.1.117:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:57:50 [2018-05-04 15:57:50,783] INFO Opening socket connection to server ip-10-0-1-117.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.0.1.117:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:57:51 [2018-05-04 15:57:51,902] WARN Session 0x1000001141b0000 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:57:51 java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host is unreachable
15:57:51 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
15:57:51 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
15:57:51 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
15:57:51 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
15:57:52 [2018-05-04 15:57:52,203] INFO Terminating process due to signal SIGTERM (kafka.Kafka$)
15:57:52 [2018-05-04 15:57:52,205] INFO [KafkaServer id=1001] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
15:57:52 [2018-05-04 15:57:52,207] INFO [KafkaServer id=1001] Starting controlled shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
15:57:53 [2018-05-04 15:57:53,962] INFO Opening socket connection to server ip-10-0-1-117.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.0.1.117:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:57:54 [2018-05-04 15:57:54,974] WARN Session 0x1000001141b0000 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:57:54 java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host is unreachable
15:57:54 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
15:57:54 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
15:57:54 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
15:57:54 at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
15:57:55 [2018-05-04 15:57:55,076] INFO [ZooKeeperClient] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
15:57:56 [2018-05-04 15:57:56,978] INFO Opening socket connection to server ip-10-0-1-117.eu-west-1.compute.internal/10.0.1.117:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
15:57:58 [2018-05-04 15:57:58,046] WARN Session 0x1000001141b0000 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
```

Comment: Why does ZooKeeper die? That's not apparent from the log. There are two things in the Kafka log that are red flags for me: "server null" and "Host is unreachable". Both indicate configuration problems, but in different places.

Comment: There's nothing in the logs to suggest why zookeeper dies, the service just starts up again with logs identical to the ones above.

I think that ECS is stopping it for some reason but I'm not sure how to investigate this possibility.

Comment: Have you tried a bigger instance? 3 x ZK and kafka in 2g seems a bit tight. An ecs service starting, dying and repeating that looks like an oom situation to me. What's the memory reservation for the services?